# Flask-sqlalchemy, good practices for generating unique key from row?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a table where the first column will have a unique key based on 2-5 columns. What is the best way for me to do this?

[image]

Comment: Any data samples? It's hard to suggest you anything based on what you said

Comment: i'm append samples

Comment: Kindly please delete this question! In what so ever manner, asking opinions and suggestions are not encouraged in StackOverflow !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create extra column for that. Dependend how you create your models, you can use composite primary key:

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model"

    article = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    telegramID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    
    type_settings = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    ...

    @property
    def composite_key(self):
        return (self.article, self.telegramID, self.type_settings, ...)
```

Now to get the specific row for given key you can use simple query

```
row = db.query(Model).get((article, telegramID, type_settings, ...))
print(row.composite_key)
```

Comment: how i can get composite key, from this way?

Comment: @ЕгорШукис I made an edit, does it answer your question?

Comment: i'm not understand, how it's work. I need to see exactly the composite key

Comment: @ЕгорШукис check it now please

Comment: I think to use this approach so that there would be only unique rows in the table

Comment: That's true, but if you want to generate that id based on other columns, then for the same columns you need to use `random` or get the same result. Is something stops you to just use autoincrement id? `id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)`